# Utilizar webkit desde JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, html-tabla

Tengo el siguiente CSS para ocultar la barra de scroll de todo mi documento, sin quitar la funcionalidad de scroll, me funciona muy bien:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Pero ahora quisiera iniciarlo con JQuery, hay alguna forma de hacerlo? no quiero hacerlo desde una hoja de estilos, sino directamente en JS

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es: **no se puede**.

Con jQuery no se pueden seleccionar los pseudoelementos.

Un truco que te permitiría activarlo/desactivarlo mediante jQuery, sería, modificar el css asociado al pseudoelemento, seleccionándolo mediante una clase y luego, añadirlo al elemento base `'html'`.

Por ejemplo..

```js
$('button').on('click', () => 
{
  if($('html').hasClass('hide-scrollbar'))
  {
    $('html').removeClass('hide-scrollbar');
  }
  else
  {
    $('html').addClass('hide-scrollbar');
  }
});
```

```css
div
{
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
}

.hide-scrollbar ::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Activar/Desactivar Scroll</button>
<div></div>
```